# Short and simple question about Android emulator and flash

Tags: android, flash, android-emulator

I think it has been established that it's not possible to install flash on Android emulator due to processor limitations. My question is though, how is it possible that youtube does work in the browser without flash, while other services, like justin.tv or ustream do not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably to do with the fact that YouTube has started using a HTML5 player instead of a flash player. I assume that the emulator can handle HTML5 videos and not flash ones. As far as I know most justin.tv channels are still using flash, there may be a few that use HTML5 though. I imagine most places will switch over eventually for better support on the iOS devices namely.

Comment: You're probably right. It seems that youtube mobile site can now use html 5 instead of flash for Android and iOS devices.